# JS parseInt() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I might be doing something wrong. Can anyone please point out why I'm getting top as object??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    topwithpx='0px';
    alert(topwithpx);
    topstr=topwithpx.substr(0,topwithpx.length-2);
    alert(topstr);
    top=parseInt(topstr);
    alert(top);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjMs9/

Thanks all: 'top' is reserved keyword (Window.top). My bad. Accepting first ans. +1 to all for quick ans.

Comment: Can you include your problem in this question? Otherwise it's going to get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: From your fiddle, I get `top`'s value as `0`. What is your question?

Comment: May I also suggest you look at JsLint http://www.jslint.com/ it will point out issues like this and others.

Comment: Thanks for edit mike. @Nivas: Really? In my chrome, I'm getting [object Window] as third popup. Please try in chrome.

Comment: next time use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Unrelated, but don't forget your radix parameter in `parseInt()` - you might end up with some unexpected results if you don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's essentially `window.top`, which is [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top). Use `var top` instead to prevent mixing local variable with global (= properties of `window` object) ones.

In fact, make `var`-ing your function variables something of a common routine - to prevent getting similar gotchas in the future. )

Comment: shadowing a global variable is not a good suggestion, you should never name a variable `top`.

Comment: Thanks for any. My bad. Thats correct. +1 for quick ans to every one.

Comment: @jbabey Because of what? When JS parser will try to determine the variable's value, it always starts from the lowest (local) scope. I do agree that it's not a good idea to use `top` instead of `window.top`, though, if you address that property.

Comment: @raina77ow shadowing is a bad practice, but this is matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `substr` to remove the `px`. `parseInt` will do this for you:

```
topwithpx='0px';
var top = parseInt(topwithpx);
alert(top);  //alerts "0"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjMs9/3/

Answer (score 3):

`window.top` is part of DOM 0 and can't be assigned a Number.

Avoid using global variables. Scope them with `var`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topwithpx, topstr, top;
    topwithpx='0px';
    alert(topwithpx);
    topstr=topwithpx.substr(0,topwithpx.length-2);
    alert(topstr);
    top=parseInt(topstr);
    alert(top);
});​
```

Comment: This is about what I was going to post :) See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) please.

Comment: Thanks for any. My bad. Thats correct. +1 for quick ans to every one.

Answer (score 3):

`top` is a default property of the `window` object ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top)). Name your variable something else.

Comment: @jAndy it's a reference to **a** window, not the current window. and yes, it is a property of the current `window` object.

Comment: I'm a little confused. `top in window` returns `true` in FF, but `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( window );` doesn't show that property at all. Chrome on the other side, gets the `top` and `self` properties correctly with `getOwnPropertyNames`

Answer (score 2):

`top` is a read-only property of the `window` ([at least for Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top), but probably all the other big browsers as well).

Just change `top` to something else like `topInt`.  Also, use `var` to declare variables (e.g. `var topInt = parseInt(...)`.  If you don't use `var`, then the `window` property is used by default, hence the read-only behavior.

By the way, it would be a bit nicer to use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Top is not a reserved word https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 1):

`top` is a `javascript window` property.
You can use top as a variable by doing this

```
var top = ...
```

Comment: top is not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Comment: @jbabey but it *is* a standard `window` property which you can't use for something else than reading, see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    topwithpx='0px';
    alert(topwithpx);
    topstr=topwithpx.substr(0,topwithpx.length-2);
    alert(topstr);
   var top=parseInt(topstr);
    alert(top);
});
```

you missing delcaration of variable